# set google map limit to my city only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my website (See screenshot below) If I type area name it shows global map with area. But I want it to work only for my latitude longitude. E.g. If I start typing it should show only area with my city. My current city is Mumbai. How Can I change the script to work such things. My website link is [www.quista.in](http://www.quista.in) incase you want to test it.

JS.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var source, destination;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute() {
            debugger;
            var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.30, 76.40),
                mapTypeControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

            //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

            var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                    var duration = (response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value / 60).toFixed(0);
                    var dvDuration = document.getElementById("dvDuration");
                    dvDuration.innerHTML = duration + 'minutes';
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                    var dvDuration = document.getElementById("dvDuration");
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.value = parseFloat(distance);
                    dvDuration.innerHTML = duration;
                    dvDuration.value = (duration);
                } else {
                    alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For restrict the search to your area, you can use `componentRestrictions` option.

> "Google dev site:   Use the `componentRestrictions` option to restrict
>   the autocomplete search to a particular country."

```
// Set the country restriction based on user input.
// Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
function setAutocompleteCountry() {
  var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  if (country == 'all') {
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions([]);
    map.setCenter({lat: 15, lng: 0});
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else {
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
    map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
    map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
  }
  clearResults();
  clearMarkers();
}
```

You can learn more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

**UPDATE**

I have created a snippet with restrict area city (india for you). I have rename the text field with your text field name `id="txtSource"`

`var countryRestrict = {'country': 'in'};` This restrict result only city for india. You can change this with other country you want restrict city.

Replace you `GetRoute()` function by the script below. No insert to a function needed.

**Snippet**

```html
<div id="locationField">
    <input id="txtSource" placeholder="From Area" type="text" />
</div>

<script>
  var autocomplete;
  var countryRestrict = {'country': 'in'};
  function initMap() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
   (
          document.getElementById('txtSource')), {
          types: ['(cities)'],
          componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
        });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

If you want just 3 citys, you must be create your own `select` drop down menu. eg:

```
<select id="city">
    <option value="pune">Pune</option>
    <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: Since I am new to google map can you tell me what changes I can make in above script to achieve my task?